# How to show icons on row hover in angular using syncfusion tables

Tags: angular, syncfusion

How to show icons on row hover in syncfusion tables.

Please see the below provided screenshot(captured from gmail)[image]

I am working with angular7.x and Syncfusion UI Components.

Please let me know if any answers available
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply append your own component with the last child of the Grid row while hovering it. Code snippet,

```
export class AppComponent {
public data: Object[];
public initialPage: Object;
public button: HTMLElement;

@ViewChild('grid')
public gridInstance : GridComponent ;  

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = data;
    this.initialPage = { pageSizes: true, pageCount: 4 };
    let btn = document.createElement("input");
    btn.type = "button";
    btn.id = "btn";
    btn.classList.add("e-btn");
    btn.value = "button";
    btn.style.marginLeft = "10px";
    btn.onclick = function(e) {
      console.log("Button clicked");
    };
    this.button = btn;
}

load(args) {
  this.gridInstance.element.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
    if((e.target as HTMLElement).classList.contains("e-rowcell")) {
        let ele: Element = e.target as Element;
        let row = parentsUntil(ele, "e-row");

        let previousButton = document.getElementById("btn");
        if(!isNullOrUndefined(previousButton)) {
          previousButton.remove();
        }

        row.lastChild.appendChild(this.button);
    }
  }.bind(this))
}
```

}

sample for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjfcyi?file=main.ts

In here I have created one new button in ngOnInit and appended that button in each row last child while hovering it.

Note: I have used Grid load event to bind the mouseover event to Grid.

Comment: Excellent @Kuralarasan , your solution is working fine.thank you very much

Comment: Kindly let me know how to remove those buttons on mouseleave

Comment: Please remove already rendered button from the Grid row, before appending the new button. You can use same mouseover event to achieve this requirement also. I have modified the above-attached code with button removing code. Please refer that code for more details.

Comment: please check now